# Disable Visual Studio ASP.Net debug from launching browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, configuration

How do I configure Visual Studio to stop launching a broswer window ever time I debug an ASP.NET project?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the properties of the web project on the Web tab (VS2008) under Start Actions, or directly under Start Options in other versions of Visual Studio.  Select the "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application" radio button.

That should do the job.  But will probably find you need a browser to test it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to beat this is to Build Solution (right click solution -> Build Solution) and just use the browser as normal. It executes faster too, which is a plus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2013.  The way i do it is to right click on the project name --> Properties --> Web --> choose "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application"